# how to optimize this code and make it faster on python

Tags: python, python-3.x

determine whether all values of a certain range are used in the array and at the same time there are no values in the array that will not be in the range. For example, the range is `[1,5]`, and the array is `[1,2,3,4,5]` - everything is correct. Or the range `[1,5]`, and the array `[1,2,1,2,3,3,4,5]` - everything is also true.
the range is `[1,5]`, and the array `[0,2,2,3,3,4,5]` is already incorrect since there is no `0` in the range, and there is also a `1` missing in the array

I did this, but it's slow with big values and terrible:

```
def func(segment, arr):
    segment_arr = []
    for i in range(segment[0], segment[1] + 1):
        segment_arr.append(i)
    arr_corr = True
    if min(arr) != min(segment_arr) or max(arr) != max(segment_arr):
        arr_corr = False
    else:
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            if arr[i] in segment_arr:
                for a in range(len(segment_arr)):
                    if segment_arr[a] in arr:
                        continue
                    else:
                        arr_corr = False
            else:
                arr_corr = False
    return arr_corr
```

Comment: Can't you just remove all values from the array and see if nothing is left, while checking that at least one removal has been made?

Comment: `s, rng = set(arr), range(*segment)` then `len(rng) == len(s) and s.issuperset(rng)`

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I thought about it, but I wanted the array not to change, and the program looked at all the values, although probably it will last longer than your option anyway.

Comment: Check for each element, keep a counter and check if the count is the size of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test if every member of a list/array/range x is in another list/array y:

```
all(e in y for e in x)
```

to test if only members of a list/array/range x are in another list/array y:

```
all(e in x for e in y)
```

The speed of these operations depends on the container type. `all` short circuits, so it will be faster when the test fails. `in` is very fast on `set` but can be slow on lists. Creation of `set` is slow and can eliminate the gains from the speed of doing `in` on a set. If you are working with numpy arrays, it will be faster to use numpy's intersect.

This should do what you're asking. If it is too slow, you will need to optimize the types. At that point, you will probably need to edit the question to give some clear examples of when it is too slow and what your constraints are:

```
def func(segment, arr):
    return all(e in segment for e in arr) and all(e in arr for e in segment)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def func(segment, arr):
    return set(list(range(segment[0], segment[1]+1))) == set(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Build a set from allowed values
2. If the resulting set has "full" length, all is correct.

```py
left, right = [1, 5]
values = [0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
values_are_correct = (
    len({i for i in values if left <= i <= right}) == (right - left) + 1
)
```